# Why does French need a "have" before a verb?

Tags: grammaire

I cannot say *Je commencé* when I want to say 'I begun', I need to say *J'ai commencé* which means 'I have begun'.

So why do I need the verb 'have' in french before the verb *commencé*?

Is there another way to say 'I begun' in French?

Comment: Your problem is not specific about French but it is about your understanding of tenses in general.  A tense in a language doesn't correspond to one particular tense in another language. For example French has a lot more tenses than, let's say English or German. *J'ai commencé* is the *passé composé*,  this tense will sometimes be expressed by the simple past, at other times by the present perfect. What you need to do is study in when French uses the *passé composé*, compared to other past tenses, like the *imparfait* or the *passé simple* ("other ways to say "I began").

Comment: [Continued] If English is your native language you must also be aware that the English present perfect is at times expressed by the *présent simple* in French. Your question is together too broad for FL, it is basic grammar. What you could do is give a specific sentence using the *passé composé*, or trying to use it and say why you hesitate between different tenses in French.

Comment: Did you mean "I began" in your question? I'm not correcting it since I don't know if it is a typo or an error (if English is not your native language). "began" is the simple past, "begun" is the past participle (as in "I have begun"), spellings not to be confused if dealing with grammar.

Comment: There are two phrases where the verb commencer is used and has the same pronunciation: "Je commençai" using the passé simple which is almost equivalent to "J'ai commencé" (passé composé).